# Explain the Concept of "endedness"

Tags: general-topology

Particularly spaces that are one-ended, two-ended, ... $k$-ended. Can anyone explain via simple examples? Also why two spaces with different ended-ness are not isomorphic.

Comment: Is the wikipedia helpful? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)

Comment: Yeah I s'pose. I read that. And I've read Spivak's book. I guess I want some intuition that I'm still somehow lacking.